# My table doesn't update when I'm searching

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My problems is that I have a table which I `refresh()` always when I'm getting my elements of database, I mean if I'm pressing GET button the table updates ok, but if I'm searching the table doesn't update and looks empty.

```
   <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Film</th>
                <th>Distributor</th>
                <th>Money</th>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Spectator</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="taking in takingstats">
                <td>{{ taking.country }}</td>
                <td>{{ taking.year }}</td>
                <td>{{ taking.film }}</td>
                <td>{{ taking.distributor }}</td>
                <td>{{ taking.money }}</td>
                <td>{{ taking.rank }}</td>
                <td>{{ taking.spectator }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button  class="btn btn-danger" ng- 
    click=deleteFilm(taking.film)>Borrar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" value="new country" ng- 
    model="newTaking.country"/>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <input class="form-control" value="new year" ng- 
    model="newTaking.year"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" value="new film" ng- 
    model="newTaking.film"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" value="new distributor" 
     ng-model="newTaking.distributor"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" value="new money" ng- 
     model="newTaking.money"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" value="new rank" ng- 
     model="newTaking.rank"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" value="new spectator" ng- 
     model="newTaking.spectator"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng- 
     click="addData()">Añadir</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>URL:<input value="borrar" class="form-control text-center" ng- 
    model="url"/></label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="send()">Get</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="putdataform(country, year, 
    film, distributor, money, rank, spectator)">Put</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deletedata(country, year, 
     film, distributor, money, rank, spectator)">Borrar todo</button>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng- 
     click="loadData()">LoadInitial</button>


     </div>

     <input class ="form-control" value="" ng-model="ranking"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <buttom class="btn btn-primary" ng- 
      click="search()">Buscar</buttom>
        </td>
     </body>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.search = function (){
                   $http.get(API+"?rank="+$scope.ranking+"").then(function 
    (response){
                    
                    $scope.takingstats = response.data;
                    console.log("Data received: "+ 
     JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
                    
                });
                };
```

Don't know why isn't work anymore while I'm searching. I can delete, post perfectly but I can't search properly. In the Google console I receive the data perfectly, but it doesn't update the table.

[image: Here is the problem ,table doesn't update]

[image]

Comment: What are you getting in the `console.log`? From what's on the page - a bunch of rows with no data in - it appears that that you're getting an array as the response, but that the objects in that array have empty strings for all those properties you're displaying on the table.

Comment: In the Google console if im seaching for rank=2 , i receive in console the film with rank=2 , the problem is doesnt update in table

Comment: i edited my question , here is an image of what console ouput me when im sarching for rank=2

Comment: Thanks, that flags up straight away that the data is an object, when it seems you wanted it to be an array of objects. I'll have to look up exactly what happens with `ng-repeat` if you pass it a non-array object, but I think this is the problem - and it can only be solved by altering what the API returns. [In particular, I don't know what happens when you want to return more than one row's worth of data.]

Comment: Change it from `<buttom>` to `<button>`

Comment: When i have one element i return an object , when i return more than one object is an array

Comment: @RoyalUp may I ask if there is a reason for that? It would be much better if your API was more consistent in what it returned. I would make it always return an array, which could be of one or more objects (or even zero or more). (You could always fix this in the frontend by checking if `response.data` was an array by using eg. `instanceof`, and wrapping it in an array if it's not - but really the backend should be giving the correct type of response in the first place.)